# Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class REST_Controller in E:\xamp\new\xampp\htdocs\p\ci\system\core\Loader.php on line 1099

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using `REST_Controller` library and so this error

> Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class REST_Controller in E:\xamp\new\xampp\htdocs\p\ci\system\core\Loader.php on line 1099

Comment: please provide some more info on your problem. what have you tried so far?

Comment: That's nice.  Have you tried to fix it on your own?  Did you follow the instructions?  What does your code look like?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are trying to load REST_Controller with $this->load->library('REST_Controller') which is not how you are supposed to use this.

[Installation Instructions](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver#installation)

You need to include the REST_Controller class either using autoloading, or by including the file yourself. Then you extend it from your main controller, with:

```
class Something extends REST_Controller {}
```